Creates the number of contacts which are equal to the numberwhich we will enter in the Number of Locations ﬁeld on the Account Object
//Code Sniippet
public static void createNewContacts(list<account>AccountHasManyList) {
        list<contact> ListOfContact = new list<contact>();
        for(account acc:AccountHasManyList) {
                integer n,b;
                Contact con = new contact();
                n = (integer) acc.NumberofLocations__c;
                for(b=0; b<n; b++) {
                  con.LastName = acc.Name;
                  con.Phone = acc.Phone;
                  con.AccountId = acc.id;
                  ListOfContact.add(con); 
                }
                
        }

        if(ListOfContact.size()>0) {
                insert ListOfContact;
        }
}


Getting this issue while running

Why it is not saving the value I am giving to the location

There is a small issue with your code, the Contact object is being instantiated only once outside the inner loop, which means the same Contact reference is being added multiple times to the ListOfContact. This will not create multiple contacts as intended.
Here is the Update code:
public static void createNewContacts(List<Account> accountHasManyList) {
        List<Contact> listOfContact = new List<Contact>();
        for(Account acc : accountHasManyList) {
                Integer n = (Integer)acc.NumberofLocations__c;
                for(Integer b = 0; b < n; b++) {
                        Contact con = new Contact();
                        con.LastName = acc.Name;
                        con.Phone = acc.Phone;
                        con.AccountId = acc.Id;
                        listOfContact.add(con); 
                }
        }

        if(listOfContact.size() > 0) {
                insert listOfContact;
        }
}

In this code, a new Contact object is created inside the inner loop for each iteration, ensuring that a unique contact is created for each location.

It Worked Thanks
